# Magento keeps sending emails from a giftcard module

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, email-scheduler

We bought and installed a gift card module from Magestore and when I was testing it on our staging website I noticed that it kept sending emails every two hours for the gift card.

How can I stop these emails?  I have read that if I run this mysql command `truncate table cron_schedule;` it will stop the emails from being sent, but won't that stop every email from being sent?

Also, any tips on how I can go about debugging this issue?  I checked the modules code and they have some `cron` jobs configured...

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <giftvoucher>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>giftvoucher/observer::autoSendMail</model>
            </run>
        </giftvoucher>
        <giftvoucherschedule>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>15 */2 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>giftvoucher/observer::sendScheduleEmail</model>
            </run>
        </giftvoucherschedule>
        <giftvoucherautodeleteimage>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>30 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>giftvoucher/observer::autoDeleteImage</model>
            </run>
        </giftvoucherautodeleteimage>
        <giftvoucherautodeleteimage1>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>45 0 1 * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>giftvoucher/observer::autoDeleteImage1</model>
            </run>
        </giftvoucherautodeleteimage1>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And when I check the `Magestore_Giftvoucher_Model_Observer` class I see the below functions:

```
/**
 * Send scheduled email
 */
public function autoSendMail()
{
    if (Mage::helper('giftvoucher')->getEmailConfig('autosend')) {
        $giftVouchers = Mage::getModel('giftvoucher/giftvoucher')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => Magestore_Giftvoucher_Model_Status::STATUS_DELETED))
            ->addExpireAfterDaysFilter(Mage::helper('giftvoucher')->getEmailConfig('daybefore'));
        foreach ($giftVouchers as $giftVoucher) {
            $giftVoucher->sendEmail();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Send scheduled email for friend
 */
public function sendScheduleEmail()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('giftvoucher/giftvoucher_collection');
    $timeSite = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_sent', array('neq' => 1))
        ->addFieldToFilter('day_store', array('notnull' => true))
        ->addFieldToFilter('day_store', array('to' => $timeSite));
    if (count($collection)) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        foreach ($collection as $giftCard) {
            $giftCard->save();
            if ($giftCard->sendEmailToRecipient()) {
                if ($giftCard->getNotifySuccess()) {
                    $giftCard->sendEmailSuccess();
                }
            }
        }
        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
    }
}
```

And in the `giftvoucher` table their is a field called `is_sent`, which has a value of `2` for the email address it keeps sending it to.

Do I just need to change the value on `is_sent` in the database?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have expected the following cron calls the sendScheduleEmail function every 2 hours.

```
    <giftvoucherschedule>
        <schedule>
            <cron_expr>15 */2 * * *</cron_expr>
        </schedule>
        <run>
            <model>giftvoucher/observer::sendScheduleEmail</model>
        </run>
    </giftvoucherschedule>
```

You can change it to not send email so often and remove the current jobs in the cron_schedule table with jobcode `giftvoucherschedule`.

If you only want the e-mail to be sent once to an e-mailaddress then you need to change a function to update the `is_sent`  value to `1` instead of `2` as soon as the e-mail is sent. However the module should do that by default.